# difference between spring-cloud-starter-dataflow-server (Data Flow Server Starter) and spring-cloud-starter-dataflow-server-local (Local Data Flow Se

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-dataflow-ui

I've recently started understanding the Spring Cloud Data Flow, also called as SCDF. I've just started looking at https://codenotfound.com/spring-batch-admin-example.html which seems very nice example, also would need more examples to really understand the use of Spring Cloud Data Flow with Spring Batch, as I've good experience with Spring Batch.

What's the difference between `spring-cloud-starter-dataflow-server` (Data Flow Server Starter) and `spring-cloud-starter-dataflow-server-local` (Local Data Flow Server Starter) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We used to ship `spring-cloud-starter-dataflow-server-local` as a standalone uber-jar for local deployments a few years ago. Similarly, we used to have `spring-cloud-starter-dataflow-server-kubernetes`, `spring-cloud-starter-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry`, and others.

However, we have consolidated all the supported platform implementations of SCDF into a single uber-jar, and that is `spring-cloud-starter-dataflow-server`. Please only use this artifact for any development/deployment, even if it is only used locally.

As for feature capabilities, we have a [dedicated page](https://dataflow.spring.io/features/) that lists them. Once you dig into the relevant sections ranging from developer guides *[example: [batch developer guide](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/2.5.0.SNAPSHOT/batch-developer-guides/)]* to [recipes](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/2.5.0.SNAPSHOT/recipes/), hopefully, you will have an idea.

And, likewise, you might find the [architecture and concepts](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/concepts/architecture/) useful for your research, which will cover the broad set of capabilities that SCDF supports including first-class orchestration experience for Spring Batch workloads.